Is the hadith authentic and why umar do this with the women
Assalamu aleykum ikhwan I had a question regarding the hadith in Musnad al Faruq 499 where it says that Umar had a woman with whom he had sex and during the sex he found that she was barren and divorced her immediately. Al Arnaut confirmed this hadith as Sahih, but I wanted to know again exactly whether it is really Sahih and why Omar treated the woman like that.Please help me answer this question

Please provide all necessary detail with the question. Quote the text including the Arabic of the hadith. Give the source where al-Arnaut has classed it as Sahih. If it is authentic then the apparent reason Umar did so is quite clear, she was advanced in age and unable to bear children whereas Umar wanted a wife who had a chance of bearing children. Divorce is permissible. See https://sunnah.com/abudawud:2050

Here is the pure Arabic wording that I have brought from a library of the narration that you can check and translate
(٤٩٩) حديث من «تاريخ الخطيب» (١) في ترجمة الفضل بن أحمد الزُّبيدي -ثقة-، قال (٢): نا زياد بن أيوب، قال ابن عُليَّة، عن أيوب، عن نافع، عن ابن عمرَ، عن عمرَ (٣): أنَّه تزوَّج امراةً، فأصابَها شمطاءَ، فطَلَّقها، وقال: حَصيرٌ في بيتٍ، خيرٌ من امرأةٍ لا تَلِدُ، واللهِ ما أقربُكُنَّ شهوةً، لكنِّي سَمِعتُ رسولَ اللهِ ﷺ يقول: «تزوَّجُوا الودُودَ، الولُودَ، فإنِّي مكاثِرٌ بكم الأُممَ يومَ القيامةِ».
رواه عنه ابن شاهين، وأبو محمد ابن معروف، وذَكَره الدارقطني، فقال: ثقة مأمون.
(١) (١٢/ ٣٧٧).
(٢) القائل هو: الزُّبيدي.
(٣) كذا ورد بالأصل. والذي في مطبوع «التاريخ»، وطبعة الدكتور بشَّار المحقَّقة (١٤/ ٣٥٣): «عن ابن عمرَ»، ليس فيه: عمر!
I do not find what you have said or claimed that "he had sex and during the sex he found that she was barren and divorced her immediately." like immediately and during the sex he found like where are these words in this narration, while this narration simply talks about he found that lady barren and as per his consensus and ijtihaad because he has the statement of Prophet SAW he divorced her.
And if you are going to say that in the wording of hadith like "I am not closer to you in desire, but I heard the Messenger of God, may God bless him and grant him peace, say: “Marry the loving, fertile woman, for I will outnumber the nations with you on the Day of Resurrection.” if you are going to quote this it will still do not work upon what you have claimed that during sex and he found and immediately he divorced at that time we do not found it rather it's simply mean by this statement that while he found that she is barren he told her that " I do not have desires and I simply put the narration of our Prophet SAW upon this matter so that's it" and it seems like by this statement he indicates that I do not want just sex which is opposite to what you have mentioned rather he also wants the childrens because he hears the Prophet SAW said and then he quoted that so it doesn't work in that way and it will be better that just like you check the sanad check and a analyse the matn too as he is a giant you can't just speak directly randomly and misinterpret please take care akhi May Allah make it easy for you and my intentions is just to counsel you as it's a bit heavy matter so please take care, Assalamu'alylkum
